# How do I get rid of the space between rows in a GridSpec?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code that builds a Figure with 2 rows and 6 columns, and uses GridSpec to span the first row on the 6 columns:

```py
fig = plt.figure()
gs = GridSpec(2, 6)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :])
df.plot(ax=ax1)

for i in range(6):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1, i])
    df2.plot(ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('imgs/figure.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

that gives me:

[image]

How do I get rid of the space in between the first and second rows? I've tried `gs = GridSpec(2, 6, hspace=0, wspace=0)` and `gs.update()` with the same parameters to no effect.

Comment: I tried `gs = GridSpec(2, 6, hspace=0)` with `matplotlib` 3.3.2 and it worked. Which version are you using?

Comment: @PieCot: Same, 3.3.2